What are the common reason for this? (I Can't Join Vertices)

For some reason, I am unable to join vertices using 'J'.


Hello, please tell what vertices you are trying to join and maybe share your file?

I was just trying to join the vertice of the the currently selected vertice to the bottom vertice of the object vertically

Use 'F' instead but since you're trying to do it on a section with a Simple Deform modifier on it you may not get the result you expect.

You have overlapping vertices that you need to merge here, otherwise the faces are ripped and the join won't work:

To merge the vertices, you can select all, press M > Merge by Distance then increase the Distance in the Operator Box, or AltZ for transparency, select the 2 vertices and M > Merge at Center.

Thanks a lot!!!

One more question tho, how do you merge it?

I've edited my answer
